# Vercel deployment with server side and client software using the same domain name

Tags: deployment, vercel

I have an API running at `api.example.com`. I have this domain set up in AWS Route53 with a DNS A record that points it to a DigitalOcean server. This works fine.

There is a front end application that I'd like to deploy on Vercel. The initial deployment works, and I can access the deployed site at: `https://example.vercel.app/`. Fantastic so far!

At this point I'd like to add a domain to Vercel so that users can access `example.com` instead of `example.vercel.app`. I'm guessing this is done behind the scenes by adding a CNAME record. When I add this domain, `example.com` works fine, but the `api.example.com` (and endpoints on that server) no longer resolve to the API running on DigitalOcean - now 404s are received and Vercel says it's not found.:

```
404: NOT_FOUND
Code: DEPLOYMENT_NOT_FOUND
ID: ..... long vercel related ID here .......
```

On Vercel, the DNS records shown are:

[image]

Nothing here stands out to me as something that would break `api.example.com` from being resolved to the IP address of the DigitalOcean server.

Is there a way in Vercel to ensure that `example.com` (and hopefully `www.example.com`) get added as domains, but `api.example.com` isn't touched? Almost seems like a wildcard domain is added behind the scenes or something like that. I could always just go buy another domain for the server side if this doesn't work.

Edit: It must be the `* CNAME -> cname.vercel-dns.com.` record that causes this!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm facing the same problem. I think the asterisk may be causing your issue.